# How do I insert html in between php speech marks

Tags: php, html

How do i insert html in between "   and " of a php bit of code.

I want to insert html code where it says `hello` - but it won't let me.

```
 $this->setError($postName, ucfirst($postName)." hello.");
} else if(strlen($postVal) > intval($max)) {
```

I want to insert this code where it says hello.

```
 <div class="alert alert-success">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <strong>Thank You!</strong> We hope to get back to you shortly.
 </div>
```

Comment: For the record, it's "double quotes" not "speech marks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $str = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>Thank You!</strong> We hope to get back to you shortly.
            </div>';

    $this->setError($postName, ucfirst($postName).$str);
} else if(strlen($postVal) > intval($max)) {
```

Comment: so i just add $str after postname? will try now

Comment: @Dom I corrected John's indentation. While the code still worked, proper indentation is a very important attribute of a programmer. It makes code readable and easier to debug. I'm writing this so you take note of it and do it yourself. From experience, I've seen many people shrug it off and say "yeah, I'll do it at the end..." that is never the case, do it properly from the beginning. It will also spare you from the wrath of future maintainers of your code as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would simply add that HTML code to a variable, and simply concatenate where you want it.

So something along the lines of:

```
$html = '<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Thank You!</strong> We hope to get back to you shortly.
</div>';

    $this->setError($postName, ucfirst($postName).$html);
} else if(strlen($postVal) > intval($max)) {
```

Hope this helps. :)
(Sorry if this belongs in a comment, can't actually comment in the question.)

Comment: I don't feel like upvoting this answer, but on the other hand, I don't understand why it deserved a downvote?!

Comment: Thanks @Christian! Yeah I don't know why I get a lot of downvotes, I don't really post anything that deserves it. Thanks for the upvote. :)